# Azure SQL DB - what is the default "guest" account for?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have been trying to research this subject and have not been able to glean any solid information, but what is the default "guest" account used for and should I revoke `connect` privilege from this account in my Production databases?

Answer (score 1):

Guest access to master database is not enabled by default on SQL Azure Database service. With on premise SQL Server you always have guest access to master database even if no user is created in it for some login you're using to connect to the server. With SQL Azure a database user should also be created on master to be able to have guest access to DMVs like sys.database_usage and sys.bandwidth_usage.

My suggestion is to create database users only since logins created on the master can be disconnected while scaling the tiers or while failovers are occurring. I don't see why a guest access should be needed for master database.